Material Grid layout is not working when flexdirection is column
I want to show the components on top of one another (flexDirection={"column"}).
For medium and large screen it should occupy as (md={3}) but for mobile screens it should occupy whole width (xs={12}).
The material grid layout is working as expected for flexDirection={"row"} as shown in attached figure. But when flexDirection set to column, it stops adapting to md or xs values.
How do I force material grid to honor md, xs values if flexDirection is column?
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import { TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";

export default function Add() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <Grid
        container
        justifyContent={"center"}
        alignItems={"center"}
        spacing={2}
        sx={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}
      >
        <Grid item xs={12} md={9} sx={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
          <TextField fullWidth></TextField>
          <Typography>xs=6 md=8</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={3} lg={1} sx={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
          <TextField fullWidth></TextField>
          <Typography>xs=6 md=8</Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}


